# Automatic Nuxt 3 plugin type detection fails after VSCode update

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

According to [the docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins#typing-plugins) Nuxt should automatically type plugins that provide methods so they show up with a $ prefixed name in `NuxtApp` and `useNuxtApp()`. And it used to, until suddenly when it no longer worked.

```js
// plugins/somePlugin.ts
export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  return {
    provide: {
      hello: (msg: string) => `Hello ${msg}!`
    }
  }
})

// app.vue
<script setup>
const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp()
console.log(nuxtApp.$hello('world')) // $hello is typed as 'unknown' but still works.
</script>
```

The only thing that changed was an automatic update of VSCode on 22 June 2023. I am now on VSCode version 1.79.2. I tried this on two separate projects and same thing, so pretty sure this is a setup issue, not a code issue.

I thought perhaps it had something to do with Volar, so checked that it is still in takeover mode. It is. The bottom right notification says `5.1.3 (takeover)`

I can fix this by manually typing things, for example by adding the following to the plugin file.

```js
declare module '#app' {
    interface NuxtApp {
        $hello: (msg: string) => void
    }
}
```

But I'd rather not go through doing that for all my plugins, especially since well, it shouldn't need it!

My current nuxt version is 3.3.2

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I resolved it by following these steps:

1. Remove the node_modules and .nuxt directories.
2. Reinstall the dependencies.
3. Regenerate the types.